# extract the maximum value available in the defined table in APDL?

Tags: ansys

Hello Ansys APDL users,
I want to extract the maximum value available in the defined table, how do I do that?
Suppose I have this code:

```
ESEL,ALL             
ETAB,EVOL,VOLU 
SET,50,LAST 
ETAB,EPS50,NL,EPEQ 
SET,32,LAST 
ETAB,EPS32,NL,EPEQ 
SADD,EPS2,EPS50,EPS32,1,-1 
SMULT,EPS_v,EPS2,EVOL,1,1
```

Now, I want to get the maximum value in table EPS_v or EPS2, how to get that?
When using Ansys in GUI mode, I can simply use the following command to extract the value:

```
PLETAB,EPS_v,AVG
*GET,EPS_max,PLNSOL,,MAX
```

But if I am running the simulation in batch mode, I can’t use these commands.
Is there any other way I can extract the maximum value from the defined table?
Or is there any other way we can save the full table as a text file?
Your responses are highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort an element table with

```
ESORT, Item, Lab, ORDER, KABS, NUMB
```

than take the max item.

In your case that would be:

```
etable,EPS50,NL,EPEQ
esort,etab,EPS50,1
*get,EPS_max,sort,0,max
```

Or you could export the etables to a txt file:

```
*GET,ecount,ELEM,,COUNT
*DIM,EARRAY,,ecount,2    
*VGET,EARRAY(1,1),ELEM,,ETAB,EPS2    
*VGET,EARRAY(1,2),ELEM,,ETAB,EPS_v    
*CFOPEN,ETABLES,txt    
*VWRITE,SEQU,EARRAY(1,1),EARRAY(1,2)
(F10.0,5X,F10.8,5X,F10.8)
*CFCLOSE
```